# Advise on device to use when tracking a moving vehicle and pushing data to an API

Tags: gps, tracking-devices, rest-api, geo-tagging

I need to determine when a van leaves or enters a geofence range, and alert a system on my side - either via an API call or email sent - so that I can digest that data for later. My blocker is finding such a device that will work with my requirements.

My goal is to be able to set a trigger of leaving/entering the geofence, and via internet connection that the device emits it will ping an API endpoint that I will build. The API endpoint will accept a POST of all data that the device can send to me. From there my API will update a database for additional logic.

If pinging an API isn't possible, I could settle for an email being sent with this POST data, and my API could scrap that email for the data that I need.

I am seeking advise on if you know a device that would meet this criteria. I am sinking tons of hours reviewing devices, their manuals, calling sales reps, etc. I am reaching out to a member of the IoT community to help me find such a device.

Comment: how about a smart phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the van as an ODB-2 port (most do) then you can just grab something like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00JZIES4M). This assumes that you need something that reports in real-time, since you'd have to pay for a data plan. That one has an app so there must be some kind of api that it is reporting to; that system may have an open api you could leverage.

Even if it doesn't, this one also sends text messages which you could forward to your application using something like Twilio. Then your app just needs to digest the text messages.

If this is for fun, building something yourself is probably more appealing. But if this is for a business application (where you don't want to mass produce something you've prototyped) then the advantages of being able to just buy an off the shelf product are numerous.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, how are you going to power your device? If you have a modern radio, or even a cigarette lighter USB adapter, then you can easily power an EDSP32, Raspberry Pi Zero W, BBC:Microbit, Arduino, etc. All of those could get the job done – with, in some cases, additionally Hat/Shields, so choose one that you are familiar with.

> I need to determine when a van leaves or enters a geofence range, and alert a system on my side - either via an API call or email sent - ***so that I can digest that data for later***. My blocker is finding such a device that will work with my requirements.

I am not sure if you need to know in real-time that the van left the geofence, or just that it happened. If the latter, then you could just simplify things incredibly by writing to SD card and interrogating that later (making sure that the drive cannot interfere with the data).

> My goal is to be able to set a trigger of leaving/entering the geofence, and ***via internet connection*** that the device emits it will ping an API endpoint that I will build. The API endpoint will accept a POST of all data that the device can send to me. From there my API will update a database for additional logic.

If you could guarantee free WiFi coverage everywhere that the van goes (possible in places like Singapore), then the ESP32 & Raspberry Pi Zero W are ideal, as they have built in WiFi. You might also consider BlueTooth communication to a ‘phone and use its data plan, but then you have to create a ‘phone app.

Probably the simplest way is to use GSM.  The Orange Pi [2g IoT](http://www.orangepi.org/OrangePi2GIOT/) and [4g IoT](http://www.orangepi.org/Orange%20Pi%204G-IOT/) are prime candidates as they have integrated SIM car compatibility. They come with a Hologram SIM card – check [here](https://hologram.io/pricing/) for pricing. They are very cheap, no monthly fee, pay only for data sent and over 196 countries across 550 carriers. See also my personal choice, at the end of this answer.

Alternatively, look for a 2g or 4g Hat/Shield for your board of choice.

> If pinging an API isn't possible, I could settle for an email being sent with this POST data, and my API could scrap that email for the data that I need.
>   I would think that if you can send email, then you can access an API.
>
> I am seeking advise on if you know a device that would meet this criteria. I am sinking tons of hours reviewing devices, their manuals, calling sales reps, etc. I am reaching out to a member of the IoT community to help me find such a device.

Well, my personal preference is ESP32 (I think that I do not need the Linux of Raspberry / Orange Pi), So I would use a [Lilygo TTGO T-Call](https://www.banggood.com/LILYGO-TTGO-T-Call-V1_3-ESP32-Wireless-Module-GPRS-Antenna-SIM-Card-SIM800L-Board-p-1527048.html?cur_warehouse=UK).
[Here](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-sim800l-publish-data-to-cloud/) is a tutorial, including code, on how to use it to publish data to the cloud.

[image]

But, if you are already proficient with Raspberry/Orange/Banana Pi, BBC Micro:bit, Arduino or anything else, you may prefer to use that.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to determine when a van leaves or enters a geofence range, and
> alert a system on my side - either via an API call or email sent - so
> that I can digest that data for later. My blocker is finding such a
> device that will work with my requirements.

For this, you can use a GPS module with the simple Arduino board and it will help to check enter and exit from a Geofencing. Basically use what @Mawg says reinstate Monica said ESP32 with the built-in GSM module so, you can check the state of the vehicle with GPS module and send the data to the cloud instantly.

> My goal is to be able to set a trigger of leaving/entering the
> geofence, and via an internet connection that the device emits it will
> ping an API endpoint that I will build. The API endpoint will accept a
> POST of all data that the device can send to me. From there my API
> will update a database for additional logic.
>
> If pinging an API isn't possible, I could settle for an email being
> sent with this POST data, and my API could scrap that email for the
> data that I need.

You can send the data to the cloud from the device in the JSON or XML format so it will be easy for you to extract.

And by data, you mean data consisting of just leaving and entering geofence time and date? or OBD and other sensors data with it.

And as @jsotola said you can build a mobile application and give to drivers and the application will do the rest of from detection of entering and exiting to sending data to the cloud just like OLA, UBER, etc.

Also, you can use the board released by Arduino MKR GSM 1400 Board with Arduino SIM and Arduino cloud connectivity cheap and easy to implement. MKR GSM 1400 can be connected with any other operator sim cards. But if you go with Arduino SIM it has restrictions to only connect to the Arduino IoT cloud.

[MKR GSM 1400 Board](https://store.arduino.cc/usa/mkr-gsm-1400)

[Arduino SIM](https://store.arduino.cc/usa/sim-card)

[Arduino IoT cloud](https://www.arduino.cc/en/IoT/HomePage)

There is an example to "Localize Your Board with an SMS" at [here](https://www.hackster.io/Arduino_Genuino/localize-your-board-with-an-sms-38e331).